# Как можно унаследовать метод другого класса

Tags: python

Вот пример:

```
class A():
  def go(self):
    print(123)
```

И мне нужно из класса B унаследовать метод go. Как это сделать?

Comment: http://pythonicway.com/education/python-oop-themes/21-python-inheritance

Comment: `class B(A): pass` и всё. Про классы в учебниках читали хоть?

Answer (score 4):

Просто унаследуйтесь от базового класса, где есть этот метод

```
class A(object):    
  def method(self):
    print('method')

class B(A):
  pass

b = B()
b.method()
```